# How to handle password protected page?

Tags: seo, noindex, password, disallow

I have an Ecommerce website, and there will be a customer profile page which is password protected. As it is protected, I assume crawler will be getting a 302 to an unprotected route(e.g. `/`) when visit that page, so it will not be meaningfully crawled.

In this case should I `noindex` the page or disallow crawler from crawling it completely? What is the best practise for SEO for password protected pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions

- You should use a `noindex` on the profile pages.
- If you are able to, then don't have a link to these pages on your site.  You can do this in the backend by removing the link if the user is not logged in.
- Otherwise set a `nofollow` on the pages with the links.
- And a 302 is the right code to return.

Comment: I have a link for the user to click on to navigate to this profile page. Should I set rel="nofollow" for the `<a>` tag?

Comment: Yes. And be aware that adding "noindex" to the *content* of  page that the bot can't see won't be much help - it needs to be in the header.